# How do you safely encode a URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

specially * and ! characters which are not encoded using encodeUriComponent

Comment: Encode it for what purpose? `*` and `!` aren't special in URIs, which is why `encodeURIComponent` doesn't encode them.

Comment: such that it can be put  in the GET string

Comment: If you mean *query string* (there is no "GET string"), it can -- with the `*` and `!`.

Comment: I want to make an ajax request in which I pass string as url parameter which may contain certain special characters and * and ! as well..using encodeUriComponent I  cannot encode these two characters....I tried replacing them referring to the answers in the previous threads ...but that doesn't seem to work..can You suggest me some other method??

Comment: **Again:** You don't have to encode them.

Comment: If I dont then it returns an error.url fails to execute and the callback of error after the ajax is called

Comment: Then "it" (whatever "it" is) is broken.

Comment: will have to check....anyways thanks for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in the comments, you **don't have to encode** `*` or `!` in a query string. This is perfectly fine, for instance: `http://example.com?foo=bar*!`

You seem intent on doing it anyway. You *can*, if you want, but **you don't have to**.

Here's how you would if it were necessary:

```
var param = "bar*!";
param = encodeURIComponent(param)
           .replace(/\*/g, '%2a') // 2a is the %-encoding of *
           .replace(/!/g, '%21'); // 21 is the %-encoding of !
var url = "http://example.com?foo=" + param;
```

(If you need to unnecessarily encode other characters, you can get the %-encoding value for them like this: `"*".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`.)

Or actually, we can automate that:

```
var param = "bar*!";
param = encodeURIComponent(param).replace(/[*!]/g, function(m) {
    return "%" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
});
var url = "http://example.com?foo=" + param;
```

...just add any others within the character class (the `[...]` in the regular expression). (This is less efficient, but it's unlikely to matter.)

But if whatever you're passing this parameter to fails with a raw `*` or `!`, I would expect it to fail with an encoded one as well.